# Twilio 11200 Error - HTTP Retrieval Failure

Tags: node.js, twilio, whatsapp

I have programmed a bot that will essentially send a mediaURL to WhatsApp. The program is unfortunately very inconsistent, where some messages go through while others don't. Turns out, each message that I send has thrown this warning: "11200 - There was a failure attempting to retrieve the contents of this URL." However, in the message details, the mediaURL is visible, so the mediaURL I am giving is in no way broken. Even with the example given to me, the debugger shows the error. Here's my code:

```
client.messages
        .create({
          from: `whatsapp:${bot_number}`,
          to: `whatsapp:${user_number}`,
          mediaUrl: link
        })
        .then((res) => {
          console.log("Message sent.")
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        })
        .done();
```

Also, here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlenK.png) of the debugger's warning with a video that delivered, yet is still being flagged.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: MIME type of MediaURL?

Comment: They're all mp4 files. video.twimg.com links to be more specific.

Comment: Can you use a tool like Postman, https://www.postman.com/ (or use your browsers developer tools), to view the returned HTTP headers or share an actual .mp4 URL in your post so we can look at the returned MIME site for that site. `Content-Type`:`video/mp4`. I tested it our fine with that MIME type. Another option to try is upload the mp4 as a Twilio Asset, https://www.twilio.com/console/assets/public, to test.

Comment: The Content-Type turned out to be video/mp4 when checking in Postman. Additionally, I also downloaded one video and saved it as an asset. Even by sending the asset file through Twilio, I got the same 11200 error. Here's the sample video I loaded: https://saffron-rabbit-6053.twil.io/assets/3ZBsNrhOuf1Hc2q3.mp4

Comment: Looking more into my message's debugger, I see that I also get "Request to StatusCallback URL was not successful." and Error "404" as the message under the 11200 error. I updated the screenshot above.

Comment: The statusCallback is not an issue specific to sending the .mp4. You must have configured a statusCallback URL and their is no application configured on that path `/demo-replys but it wouldn't prevent you from sending the WhatsApp attachment.